# How do I pass a value to an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have what I think is called an object(?) in JavaScript:

```
     paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
         'merchantnumber': "XXXXXX",
         'amount': '10500',
         'currency': "DKK"
     });
```

Now I want to set the amount value to the object. Something like:

```
paymentwindow.amount = '20000';
```

However, that does not work. I am sure this is simple, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Post your object definition to make things easy to us.

Comment: Can you post your code about the PaymentWindow object?  You are passing an object in and unless you are parsing the input to local variables, it would look more like `paymentwindow.yourvariablename.amount = '20000';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now i want to be able to set the amount from outside the object.

This is easy or impossible, depending on how the object looks like.

If the constructor is set up like this:

```
function PaymentWindow(options) {
    this.amount = options.amount;
}
```

then it's easy and works exactly as you propose. Anything attached to `this` becomes a public property.

However, if the constructor is set up like this:

```
function PaymentWindow(options) {
    var amount = options.amount;
}
```

then it's impossible, because `var amount` is private to the constructed object.

Comment: Sorry guys, i wasn't clear. I havn't written the function myself. It is a function used buy epay as an payment gateway. So i don't have the luxury of "re-writing" the function.

Comment: Every function in JavaScript can be rewritten (except for some built-in language features). Just declare a new one with the same name.

Comment: Rather than override part of the "epay" (Ebay?) API, it'd be better to find some usage/example docs for using it (which hopefully exist). Otherwise, if it's JavaScript, you can likely obtain and browse the source code to see how they wrote it.

Comment: It is a danish payment gateway ePay, unfortunatly no documentation about it, and can't get hold of the suppert. However i found a detour to solve the problem, so it is good. I will leave the question open a little bit for som inspiration.

Comment: That's the nice thing about JavaScript. You always have access to the source. You can make any modifications you like, any time, even to code you did not write yourself. — In any case, if the objects were designed in a way that prevents you from updating one of the properties, there's a good chance that you are using them in the wrong way. Maybe `amount` was not meant to be updated from the outside in the first place. Maybe there is a `setAmount()` method. Maybe you could simply construct a new object with the modified value.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it first in the constructor

```
function myObject(){
   this.myMemberVariable = 123;
   this.anotherOne = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That must be because the Object PaymentWindow is undefined. This works in the JS console in Chrome even:

```
paymentwindow = new Object({
         'merchantnumber': "XXXXXX",
         'amount': '10500',
         'currency': "DKK"
     });

// Object {merchantnumber: "XXXXXX", amount: "10500", currency: "DKK"}

paymentwindow.amount = '20000'

// Object {merchantnumber: "XXXXXX", amount: "20000", currency: "DKK"}
```

Make sure PaymentWindow is available in the scope where you instantiate it by using the 'new' keyword. If you open up the JavaScript console in your browser after running your original code, you will probably see this:

```
ReferenceError: PaymentWindow is not defined
```